# Conversion of Matlab function into Python function

Tags: python, function, matlab

The following function is written on Matlab. Now, I need to write an equivalent python function that will produce a similar output as Matlab. Can you help write the code, please?

```
function CORR=function_AutoCorr(tau,y)

% This function will generate a matrix, Where on-diagonal elements are autocorrelation and 
% off-diagonal elements are cross-correlations
% y is the data set. e.g., a 10 by 9 Matrix.
% tau is the lag value. e.g. tau=1

Size=size(y);
N=Size(1,2); % Number of columns
T=Size(1,1); % length of the rows
for i=1:N
  for j=1:N
      temp1=0;
    for t=1:T-tau
    G=0.5*((y(t+tau,i)*y(t,j))+(y(t+tau,j)*y(t,i)));
    temp1=temp1+G;
    end
    CORR(i,j)=temp1/(T-tau);
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `y` is a numpy Array, it would be pretty near something like (although I have not tested):

```
import numpy as np

def function_AutoCorr(tau, y):
    Size = y.shape
    N = Size[1]
    T = Size[0]
    CORR = np.zeros(shape=(N,N))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            temp1 = 0
            for t in range(T - tau):
                G=0.5*((y[t+tau,i]*y[t,j])+(y[t+tau,j]*y[t,i]))
                temp1 = temp1 + G
            CORR[i, j] = temp1/(T - tau)
    return CORR

y = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [6,7,8], [13,14,15]])
print(y)
result = function_AutoCorr(1, y)
print(result)
```

The resulting `CORR` matrix for this example is:

[image]

If you want to run the function for different `tau` values, you could do, in Python:

```
result = [function_AutoCorr(tau, y) for tau in range(1, 11)]
```

The result will be a list of autocorrelation matrices, which are numpy arrays. This syntax is called a list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you @luizbarcelos . For some reason, this code is not working. If you have time, can you please test it?

Comment: Hi @MMKarim, I have updated it with a fully functional example after analyzing the code a bit more. Please let me know if it returns the same result as in MATLAB for the same example. Else I can further help debugging it

Comment: Hi @luizbarcelos, Thank you. It does work. I have another problem in calling this function inside a for loop for tau=1:10. The Matlab function is:                                                                     `for tau=1:M
    C{1,tau}=function_AutoCorr(tau,X) ;
end`                                                                                                                                   
 This gives me a total of 10 (N by N) matrices. How to write a similar code in Python?

Comment: Hi @MMKarim, I will edit my answer to account for that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use NumPy. They even have a [guide for Matlab users](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html).

Here are some useful tips.

### Defining a function

```
def auto_corr(tau, y):
    """Generate matrix of correlations"""
    # Do calculations
    return corr
```

### Get the size of a numpy array

```
n_rows, n_cols = y.shape
```

### Indexing

Indexing is 0-based and uses brackets (`[]`) instead of parentheses.